# Autodesk Forge -Design Automation- Translation - Cloud credit consumption

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are developing an application on Forge-Design Automation for Revit. In this, we are executing Revit file(.Rvt) on a forge using Design automation API which consumes $6/hr. forge cloud credit as it treats my Revit file as a complex job(600 MB size file). After execution on DA ,i am using Model derivative API to translate the model to show in a web based forge viewer.

The model derivative consumes $1.5/complex jobs.

If I execute a job for 4 times, it consumes forge cloud credit as follows:
Design Automation takes 15mins to process each job = 15 mins x 4 = 60 mins =1hr.
Cloud credit is $6/hr 
Model derivative will take $1.5 x 4 = $6/hr.
Total credit consumed is $6 +$6 = $12

Here, the Forge cloud credit consumes for viewer(Translation) is consuming more than Design automation cloud credit.

We storing the file on Forge bucket itself so that we can share the translated file link to end user. Here it consumes more cloud credit for viewer as I have stated above.
If I store the file on BIM360(I hope we no need to translate on forge), I need to get the user login for 3-legged authentication to push the file from forge(after DA execution) to BIM360.

Could you please suggest the better way to store and share the online web viewer to end user ?.

Regards,
Durai

Comment: Hi, quick confirm, the workflow is: Revit file A --(Design Automation Revit)--> Revit file B ---(Model Derivative service)--> Forge viewer ? And you question is how to save cloud credit with better solution, right?

Comment: Yes, you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

First, if your user has BIM360 license, I would suggest to store your files on **BIM 360 Docs**, it will translate your file automatically, and there is no extra cost for translation. So the workflow would be as follow(without Forge translation service cost, only Design Automation service cost):

**Revit model from BIM 360 Docs as input --(Design Automation Revit)--> Updated Revit model to BIM 360 Docs as output --> Forge Viewer of your App**.

If you want to check how to use model from BIM 360 Docs as input/output for Design Automation Revit, you can check the file upgrade sample at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-upgradefiles-revit

If you want to check how to view the model from BIM 360 Docs, please check out learn tutorial at https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels, and source code at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels

Comment: We tried with BIM360 with 3 legged authentication and it is working fin. But our requirement was uploading file to Bim 360 with 2-legged authentication.

We have taken another approach to upload file to BIM 360 after downloading output file from DA using 2-legged Authetication with x-user-id header and it is working fine.

Is there a way to upload file directly from Forge DA bucket to Bim 360 using 2-legged Authentication and x-user-id header?

Thank you for your support.

-Durai

Comment: please check the sample I mentioned in the reply, it actually directly upload file from Forge DA to BIM 360 using 3-legged token, but yes, you can do the same with 2 legged token and x-user-id header....